# Show Div on Mouseover after three second

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want on first click it will show after 3 seconds but after the first click when I clicked it will shown before 3 seconds:

```
function Func1()
{

document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "visible" ;

}

function Func1Delay()
{

setTimeout("Func1()", 3000);

}

function Func2Delay()
{

document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility = "hidden" ;

}
```

Comment: sorry but your description doesn't make sense (at least not in english)

Comment: please expand your question; eg. how is Func1Delay() called etc?

Comment: I want to show div on mouseover after 3 seconds .. that is happening right now but after that i want div before 3 seconds .. is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Your English or description is very poor, but from what I understand, you want something like this :

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1'),t;
function changeStyle(element,prop,value){
    element.style[prop] = value;
}

function showDiv(){
    changeStyle(div,'opacity','1');
}

function hideDiv(){
    changeStyle(div,'opacity','0');
}

div.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
    t = setTimeout(showDiv,3000);
},false);

div.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    hideDiv();
},false);​
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/TSVA5/
You have to hover the "invisible" div and it will show after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

the markup:

```
    <input type="button" value="clickme" onmouseout="ClearIntv()" onmouseover="DelayShow('showMe',5000)" />
    <div id="showMe" style="display:none;background-color:red;width:50px;height:50px;">

    </div>
```

the script:

```
    var intv;
    function DelayShow(timeOutMs) {
        var elm = document.getElementById("showMe");
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var end = now + timeOutMs;;
        intv = setInterval(function () {
            now = new Date().getTime();
            if (now >= end) {
                elm.style.display = "block";
                clearInterval(intv);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    function ClearIntv() {
        clearInterval(intv);
    }
```

Activates the counter on MouseOver, and cancels on MouseOut